# How call webservice in every hour if internet connected to device

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver, background-service

I want to call web service in the background when internet is connected. If it is connected I want to call in every one hour if internet is turned off then stop the service. How can I? It needs to work for all versions from 16 to 27.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is broadcast in android which notifies you if network status changed. In there you can register alarm manager for a period of one hour and check if the internet was connected then call the web service.

If broadcast informed you the network was disconnected then you can cancel your alarm manager.

Here is documentation for listening to network status change:

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring

and here is good tutorial about using alarm manager in android 
https://en.proft.me/2017/05/7/scheduling-operations-alarmmanager-android/

also google introduced workManager which does this work for you in the very simple way

> The WorkManager API makes it easy to specify deferrable, asynchronous
>   tasks and when they should run. These APIs let you create a task and
>   hand it off to WorkManager to run immediately or at an appropriate
>   time. For example, an app might need to download new resources from
>   the network from time to time. Using these classes, you can set up a
>   task, choose appropriate circumstances for it to run (like "only while
>   device is charging and online"), and hand it off to WorkManager to run
>   when the conditions are met. The task is still guaranteed to run, even
>   if your app is force-quit or the device is rebooted.

here is link to documentation :

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: but for oreo we need to make a notification in service and we have to regester brodcast in activity i dont no how to do this please send me a code if you have thanks for your ans